# Number format exception but not parsing an int?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
title = request.getParameter("title");
    author = request.getParameter("author");

    search(title, author);

    ArrayList<Book>books = new ArrayList();

    while(conn.rs.next()){
        Book book = new Book(conn.rs.getString(1), conn.rs.getString(2), conn.rs.getString(3));
        books.add(book);
    }
    System.out.println(books.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(books.get(i).getBookID());
    }

    request.setAttribute("Book", books);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jspSearch.jsp");
    rd.include(request, response);
```

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="Book" items="${Book}">
            <tr>
                <td>${Book.bookID}</td>
                <td>${Book.title}</td>
                <td>${Book.author}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

I am getting a numberFormatException on

```
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

and

```
        processRequest(request, response);
```

but I'm not doing anything with parsing a string to a number? I've been stuck on this for most of the day and I'm not doing anything with numbers so

```
Nov 30, 2015 10:11:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [showAllBooks] in context with path [/a3Austin] threw exception [java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "bookID"] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "bookID"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:157)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:70)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:110)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:943)
    at org.apache.jsp.jspShowAll_jsp._jspService(jspShowAll_jsp.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at web.showAllBooks.processRequest(showAllBooks.java:48)
    at web.showAllBooks.doGet(showAllBooks.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

out.write("\t\t\t\t<td>");
      out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${Books.bookID}", java.lang.String.class, (javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext)_jspx_page_context, null));
      out.write("</td>\r\n");
```

Comment: The exception's stack trace would tell you exactly where it's happening (and potentially why). It's unfortunate you decided not to post it.

Comment: I added the stack trace didn't think of adding it because i pointed out where it said the error was

Comment: What's the corresponding, **minimal** JSP that causes this exception?

Comment: <c:forEach var="Book" items="${Book}">
   <tr>
    <td>${Book.bookID}</td>
    <td>${Book.title}</td>
    <td>${Book.author}</td>
   </tr>
  </c:forEach>
it would be that if I'm thinking of the right thing

Comment: `ArrayList<Book>books = new ArrayList();` make up your mind about using generics or not

Comment: You could try changing request.setAttribute("Book", books); to  request.setAttribute("Books", books); and change <c:forEach var="Book" items="${Book}">  to  <c:forEach var="Book" items="${Books}">

Comment: same error still occurs with that change :(

Comment: In the stacktrace you have at org.apache.jsp.jspShowAll_jsp._jspService(jspShowAll_jsp.java:129    So what line is 129?  You have to look in Tomcat's work folder for the file called jspShowAll_jsp.java

Comment: What is the type of the field bookId  in Book?

Comment: when i click on the stack trace it says source not found and the type is string

Comment: Are you saying that bookId is a String?  Did you look in Tomcat's work folder for line 129 of the file  jspShowAll_jsp.java  ?

Comment: Yes bookID is a string and I found it editted it in to the topic

Comment: You didn't do what rickz suggested. You have a list of **several** books. The attribute holding that list should be named `Books`(or preferrably `books`), with a final `s`, to indicate that it's a list of several books (plural form). Since you want to iterate on that list, you want `<c:forEach items="Books" ...>`. Inside this loop, you want to refer to the current, **singular** book. It's thus a single book, and you should thus refere to it as `Book`(or preferrably `book`): singular form. So you want `<c:forEach items="Books" var="Book" >`.